# R code problems about scan()

Tags: r

I am reading someone's code, but can not understand the `scan()` and `readLines()` part.

```
f <- file("stdin")
open(f)
FN <- scan(f,n = 2, quiet = TRUE)        ## first line
ncol <- FN[1]                            ## ncol=2
nrow <- FN[2]                            ## nrow=100
training <- readLines(f,n=nrow)          ## read line from 2 to 101
tra <- read.table(text = training)
test.n <- scan(f, n = 1, quiet = TRUE)   ## line 102
test <- readLines(f,n=test.n)            ## read line from 103 to 107 
test <- read.table(text = test)
```

I have no idea how these `scan()` and `readLines()` work. Could anyone explain a little bit?

Comment: Did you at least start by reading the `?scan` and `?readLines` help page??

Comment: Yes, I read. but not sure if I am understand the explanation. for scan(), n :the maximum number of data values to be read. In this case, n=2, so reads 2 numbers (first line). Then the readLines() reads 100 rows, but why it starts from line 2? And why the scan(f, n=1) reads line 103 (only one value in this line)?

Comment: They are all reading from the same connection `f`. Each operation picks up where the last one left off.